# Cannot understand how to write a testcase for weekdays in python using unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, dayofweek

I have a function in python which takes weekday as a parameter and returns an int on successfull weekday, im a newbie in python unittesting and i wish to know how to write the unittest case for the same. here's the function:

```
def dayNameFromWeekday(weekday):
    if weekday == "Monday":
        return 0
    if weekday == "Tuesday":
        return 1
    if weekday == "Wednesday":
        return 2
    if weekday == "Thursday":
        return 3
    if weekday == "Friday":
        return 4
    if weekday == "Saturday":
        return 5
    if weekday == "Sunday":
        return 6
```

and here's the testfile

```
class Utils(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dayNameFromWeekday(self, weekday):
        if weekday == "Monday":
            return 0
        elif weekday == "Tuesday":
            return 1
        elif weekday == "Wednesday":
            return 2
        elif weekday == "Thursday":
            return 3
        elif weekday == "Friday":
            return 4
        elif weekday == "Saturday":
            return 5
        elif weekday == "Sunday":
            return 6
        else:
            return -1  # Any error message

    res = self.test_dayNameFromWeekday("Monday")
```

and i have no idea how to write a test case for this function, please enlighten me with the way the things are done in unittest python..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import unittest
class Utils(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dayNameFromWeekday(self, weekday):
        if weekday == "Monday":
            return 0
        elif weekday == "Tuesday":
            return 1
        elif weekday == "Wednesday":
            return 2
        elif weekday == "Thursday":
            return 3
        elif weekday == "Friday":
            return 4
        elif weekday == "Saturday":
            return 5
        elif weekday == "Sunday":
            return 6
        else:
            return -1  # Any error message
    def runTest(self):
        res = self.test_dayNameFromWeekday("Monday")
        print(res)

res = Utils()
res.run()
```

Comment: if i use this code for my test file in a function named test_dayNameFromWeekday(self)...then i get an error like weekday not defined..besides this, isnt there a way to write a test case using assertEqual statement?

Comment: @cerebral_assassin You are writing wrong function name. It should be ```test_dayNameFromWeekday(self,weekday)```

Comment: @cerebral_assassin Change the function name to ```def test_dayNameFromWeekday(self,weekday):``` and let me know

Comment: yes i tried it but this time it throws a TypeError: test_dayNameFromWeekDay() missing 1 required positional argument: 'weekday'

Comment: @cerebral_assassin Check my updated code. Do the same what I did

Comment: @cerebral_assassin Are you using ```class```??

Comment: its still showing the same error...yes i am using it in my test.py file...its class weeks(unittest.case): and then comes your answer. in my py file there is no class(the function which i have written)

Comment: @cerebral_assassin If you are using class then you need to call function as ```res = self.dayNameFromWeekday("Monday")```

Comment: @cerebral_assassin Please use ```res = self.dayNameFromWeekday("Monday")``` this and try once

Comment: please see my updated question. i have edited the testfile..by adding a self. i get a nameError..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206683/discussion-between-cerebral-assassin-and-vaibhav-jadhav).